# Blender claims my platform is unsupported and wont open

Tags: error, gpu

I use a macbook air 2015 model,Mac Os montery 12.6 and was having problems in blender 3.9 where it wouldn't render one of my 2d grease pencil drawings and so i updated the application hoping this issue would be solved only to open it and see this
[image: this is what shows whenever I open it]

Comment: Hello and welcome! A Blender version 3.9 does not exist. Which one do you mean?

Comment: If you just went to the Blender download page and downloaded the latest version you will have Blender 4.0 which has updated graphics requirements. See the bottom of [this](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0) page in the Blender manual.